# Pseudocode of brute-force algorithm that finds largest product of two numbers in a list

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, products

This one will require a basic knowledge of some computer science concepts. I am trying to come up with a pseudocode brute-force algorithm that finds the largest product of two numbers in a list $a_1, a_2, ...a_n (n\ge 2)$.  Right now, I have:

for ($i=1$ to $n-1$)

$a_i$$ = a_{i-1}$ $ * a_{i+1}$

for ( $j = {j+1}$ to $n$)

$a_j$$ = a_{j-1}$ $ * a_{j+1}$

end for

end for

return $a_i$

return $a_j$

end procedure

However, this is not correct, and I can't figure out what else I'm supposed to do to be able to traverse the entire list, get products of each item in the list, and return the largest products in the lists. I feel like it's something simple I'm missing, but I can't figure it out. Any advice?

Comment: Find two largest and two smallest numbers in the list and pick the pair with largest product.

Comment: But how do I do that? Could I use a max() algorithm to find the two largest numbers in the set, then take the product of those two numbers? @A.S.

Comment: Do you understand the algo to find max in one pass over the array? Do the same, but instead of comparing a new element to the running max, compare it to the running 2nd largest/smallest and then to running max/min if needed.

Comment: What exactly is the Question to be answered here?  Checking for program (even pseudocode) correctness is off-topic.  The best that could be read into the post as it stands is that "Any advice?" is a request for checking correctness of an algorithm (or how to check an algorithm) rather than for the code itself.

Comment: I wasn't looking for code, I was looking for logic. Pseudocode is mostly English anyway. @hardmath

Comment: If logic is what you're looking for, then you should learn how to do what *A.S.* described. It's an extremely basic thing in programming.

Comment: Well, the code you posted makes little sense. First, it only tries to compute products of elements two positions apart and second you are actually overwriting the values you are given and losing info.

Answer (score 3):

```
large = a_1 * a_2
for(i = 1 to n)
    for(j = i+1 to n)
        if(large < a_i * a_j)
            large = a_i * a_j
```

At the end, this should give you the largest product possible.

(I think I have taken all the possibilities, but if I haven't, please tell me).

Comment: You program might return $a_i \cdot a_i$ as the largest number. It seems to me that OP looks for the largest product of two distinct elements in his list (well - at least elements with distinct indices).

Comment: Stefan is right. Second loop starting from $i$ does not **prevent** $i = j$.

Comment: Just made it $i+1$

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
x:= a_1 \cdot a_2
for(i = 1; i \le n; i++){
  for(j=i+1 ; j \le n; j++){
    x := max{x, a_i \cdot a_j};
  }
}
return x;
```

Comment: What's up with the downvotes?

Comment: Not efficient. Come on, use the hint provided by *A.S.*!

Comment: @user21820 While you are right that this isn't very efficient - I don't think that it deserves a downvote - especially considering the title of this question. I even dare to argue that this sort of algorithm might be more valuable to the OP, since it allows him to better understand the problems with his code.

Comment: Well... There's a limit to how bad inefficiency one should close an eye to, and especially when the method has already been described by someone else. Otherwise you'd have to accept an answer that goes through every pair, and for each pair checks whether its product is at least as much as the product of every other pair! Surely that's **true** brute-force. The other reason is that if people always give suboptimal solutions, this stackexchange site will be full of suboptimal solutions. If you don't want to provide the proper solution, I'll do it, but I wanted to let you and upvote yours.

Comment: Oh and you can always have your brute-force solution in your answer together with the asymptotically optimal one.

Comment: The Question, while it may be somewhat off-topic, asks about a brute-force algorithm.  Quadratic complexity (in the length of the list of numbers) seems exactly the inefficiency called for by the OP.  Replacing it with various "faster" approaches may demonstrate cleverness but be unresponsive to the actual problem posed.